# For new sites, question downvoters should be forced to explain themselves

Tags: feature-request, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I have no problem with downvoting on established sites, where the range of valid topics should be well understood.   But on new sites, where things are just getting started, should there be a mild impediment to downvoting questions?

Comment: Is that a real problem that we have on new sites now?

Comment: And in a supreme turn of irony, no one will explain why this question is downvoted. =P

Comment: When reading this request, it translated in my mind to "can we have a feature that ensures that people do not downvote questions however bad or unsuitable they are?".

Comment: If they're bad or unsuitable, it shouldn't be hard to explain that, should it.

Comment: Forcing people to do _anything_, especially explain themselves will cause most of them to abandon the action. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have yet to see a young site where *excessive down-voting* is a problem. Yes, explanations are helpful - perhaps even more helpful on a young site than on an established one - but I'd have to see evidence that discussion of problems with down-voted posts isn't happening.

Comment: The bigger problem is that there is *not enough* downvoting on young sites.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't like people named "Wilson" ever since he abandoned Tom Hanks on that raft in the middle of the ocean.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Voting is critical to new sites as the community works out what kinds of questions should be entertained. If we impede down voting, even just a little, it would probably result in the site taking much longer to graduate, or not graduating at all.

Down voting questions that you don't feel are a good fit is your way of saying "I'm a part of this community, and I don't think this will be good for us". We'd be foolish to get in the way when it comes to that.

Additionally, your pro-tem moderators (or SE employees at the beginning) desperately need this kind of signal so they can act on behalf of the majority, at least until a clear definition of scope can be established.

If you take that away, you end up with people that don't vote, and moderators that are reluctant to moderate as their binding vote now expresses fewer opinions, or perhaps only their own opinion.

For a new community, that would spell disaster.

Answer (score 2):

The moment you put a barrier like that on downvotes, you will get orders of magnitude less downvotes.

You may think it is a good thing, but it is not.

It will allow junk questions (irrelevant, bad, jokes, spam - choose your poison) to remain open indefinitely on the new site. Exactly what you **don't want** on a new site that is trying to gain a bunch of good, relevant questions.